# How to fill up a side bar which only has a form with 3 fields?

Tags: forms, layout, sidebar

So I have a page where left sidebar takes 25% and the actual thing takes up 75% on the right.

Basically a user would select something from the main app and fill out the form in the left side bar and submit.

The problem is there are only 3 fields for the form. I currently put them at the top of the side bar, and I have 2 buttons at the bottom of the sidebar one for submit another for reset selection.

However, this would leave almost 1/2 to 2/3 of the sidebar blank. 
And I don't think I can easily fill up the space with say increase font size and/or increase margin between them..

Also I am putting the label on top of each field, this makes them fill up more space vertically but then they only take 1/2 of the space horizontally.

Any suggestion on how to improve the layout in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason this form is in the side bar and not in the 75% section?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, does the 25% sidebar is necessary and fixed for only those requirements you mentioned because if that is the only use with 3 fields, then you can go ahead and once user select one of the option, for that short time open the 25% sidebar, let the user fill the info and let them select one of the 2 buttons at the bottom and close the side bar, so that you can use the rest of the space (2) once user select something, instead of sidebar, show 25% drop down with 3 fields and 2 buttons. I hope this helps?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the design of the whole thing? I think maybe we could work on something here :)

Comment: @adriennetacke the 75% is basically a google map with bunch of shapes, so I think having a separate form is better in this case

Comment: @LoveProgramming Ah, that makes sense. Do you have a mockup so that we can see what you're working with? :)

Comment: @WenG The idea is there is a map with bunch of shapes/area on it, and a user can select some of them by clicking or box selection. Then he/she would input infos for those selected areas (names, owner etc..) and click submit. This whole thing is a overlay on top of another popup which I have no control over, so another popup inside this may not be a good option.

Comment: @SourabhRangdal so the whole thing is an overlay on top of another popup whichI have no control over. They don't like the idea of a popup on top of a popup so I guess I can't use dropdown either.. There are some restrictions and I'm just trying to do what I can to at least make it nicer from my part.

Comment: @adriennetacke http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1756/ here you go, its very rough though.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a sidebar and you can't move the form horizontally. It can't be that an obvious option?

Comment: @MadalinaTaina The overall shape is about 16:9, with more width than height. How is it a good idea to put a form horizontally when there are already less space there.

Comment: Possible to share print screen and task flow as I may have better solution

Comment: @LoveProgramming I just checked your message, give me a day, I will share the task flow and print screen. One request, because i've older browser i'm not able to upload image here in ux-stackexchange but I will upload it at Pinterest and share you the link. i hope this helps?

Comment: @SourabhRangdal I would love to see the pinterest if you got one!

Comment: https://au.pinterest.com/pin/180284791312566082/pop-up-1: simple display the fields horizontally, so that user can view and submit / enter the data

Comment: https://au.pinterest.com/pin/180284791312566083/pop-up-2: in this pop-up, to fill the form, user has to click button [FORM], the form will appear on left column. Again, if user click to button [FORM] the left-column-form will disappear / close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what I understand so far, **I think there's nothing wrong with the extra space**. It is much cleaner and gives you more flexibility with the layout if you need to make any changes (add more fields, more options, etc).

If you're still concerned, I would try something like this:

[image: Side Bar Form with few input fields]

Make all of your elements a little bit bigger and leave some ample room between them. This takes up more space but probably doesn't feel as "empty" as your initial layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the form could be displayed horizontally, on the top or after the main app. A second option is to put it on a modal.

Comment: As I replied to others in comment, popup on top of popup is not an option